# How to escape HTML tags in errors in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm using Rails 3.2.22 and simple_form 2.1.3

Some of our fields have duplicate checking and the error includes a link to the duplicated record (so the user can check if it's just the name that's duplicated, or if they don't need to create the record).

However, we've recently switched from a customised form builder to Simple Form, and now these error messages are escaped, displaying the escaped error.

I reproduced this issue in [a minimal app](https://github.com/AJFaraday/simple_form_issue_app):

In the Doohickey model:

```
  validate :unique_name_validation
  def unique_name_validation
    other_doohickey = Doohickey.find_by_name(name)
    if other_doohickey
      errors.add(
        :name,
        "This name is already taken by <a href='/doohickey/#{other_doohickey.id}'>#{other_doohickey.name}</a>"
      )
    end
  end
```

In the UI:

```
<%= simple_form_for @doohickey do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :name %>
  <%= form.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

The UI shows the HTML on the page itself...

[image]

There's also some configuration in /config/initializers.rb, but I haven't found a way there to turn off this escaping.

How can I display links from errors using Simple Form?

Comment: You can try with .html_safe `"This name is already taken by <a href='/doohickey/#{other_doohickey.id}'>#{other_doohickey.name}</a>".html_safe`

Comment: @SebastiánPalma Thanks! That works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bearing in mind the content won't never be nil, then you can use `html_safe`, like:

```
"This name is already taken by <a href='/doohickey/#{other_doohickey.id}'>#{other_doohickey.na‌​me}</a>".html_safe
```